# What Species is Groot?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, groot

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, The Collector implies that Groot is his own species (he says something like: "I have never met a Groot before") but as far as I can tell there is no evidence for Groot being a recognized Marvel race outside of the GOTG film.

Is it possible that Groot is of the H'ylthri species?

> H'ylthri are an other-dimensional, sentient plant race. Their bodies are vegetable fiber with few vital organs, making them difficult to injure. They possess superhuman strength to an unspecified level, can control other plant life, and extend both tangling vines or poisonous barbs to knock mammals unconscious. They can grow humanoid doppelgangers with the originals' personality and memories

Or is Groot one of a kind like Rocket?

And if so how did The Collector recognize him?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is, "I am Groot."

Comment: Clearly he's an Ent.

Comment: He is Groot. I'd say The Collector had it right.

Comment: @BBlake - you mean distant cousing of treebeard ??? so floral collosus are from middle-earth ?? :)

Comment: @BBlake Plot Twist: Groot is an EntWife.  The Ents lost them when they were abducted by the Kree.

Comment: Can you cite the passage you've quoted please?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200010/are-other-groots-also-named-groot

Answer (score 55):

According to [Marvel](https://www.marvel.com/characters/groot/in-comics), his species is 
 simply "Groot" within the main Earth-616 comics continuity.

[image: 616 description]

Interestingly, until recently, Marvel's site [listed him as a Flora Colossus](http://web.archive.org/web/20150320092535/http://marvel.com/universe/Groot)

[image: Flora Colossus]

In either case, he is one of many of his species, and not unique.

Marvel Wikia explains [the Flora Colosssus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Flora_colossi)

> The Flora colossus are tree like beings from Planet X the capital of the branch worlds. The Flora Colossus are ruled over by the "Arbor Masters" who teach the children of the species with "Photonic Knowledge," which is the collected knowledge of the Arbor Masters of generations, and is absorbed through Photosynthesis, this is an highly advanced education making the Flora Colossus's geniuses. Planet X's biome is managed by the "Maintenance Mammals", type of small squirrel-like beings.

[image: Lookit all the Groots!]
<sup>Those are multiple Floral Colossus beings, not replicated Groots.</sup>

---

Within the MCU, marvel [identifies him as a "Flora Colossus"](https://www.marvel.com/characters/groot/on-screen).

[image: Flora Colossus]

[image: Groot Bio]
<sup>(Image from [the official movie site](http://web.archive.org/web/20140302003745/http://marvel.com/guardians))</sup>

Comment: Thanks :) do you also know how the collector knew Groot was called Groot? sorry it just bugs me

Comment: My guess would be that, as Marvel Wikia explains, all Flora Colossus sound like they're just saying "I am Groot" all the time. If this holds true for the MCU, he would likely just be referencing this fact more than Groot's name specifically.

Comment: Makes sense :D thanks for clearing that up :P

Comment: curse you and your better picture.

Comment: Regarding your note on `Floral` vs. `Flora`, I'd surmise that `Flora Colossus` could be a typo or mistaken knowledge in the unofficial wikia, given the low-quality writing in the wikia quote there.

Comment: Galactic Roots. Ha!

Answer (score 27):

His species is a *Flora colossus*, though the name is never used within the movie.

In the comics, he's from Planet X (indeed, he's the monarch of that planet.)

In the movie, his origin has been changed to being from a planet called Taluhnia:

[image]

Either way, the implication is that he comes from a planet of creatures of the same species, so no, he's not unique.

Comment: > In the movie, his origin has been changed to being from a planet called Taluhnia.

Did you hear that in the movie or in an interview? I missed this explanation somehow.

Comment: @minhundje It's right there on the screen: "Humanoid Plant Inhabitant of Taluhnia"